# MVC Ajax, Post to Controller base64 string

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my project I send post json data object. One item of this object is base64 string. When base63 string is too long, my request doesnt reach to controller. In my opinion , due to length of parameter,it doesnt work. I couldnt find any solition.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateInput(false)]      
        public ActionResult Add(Page item)
        {
            if (item == null
                || string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Title)
                || string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.SeoUrl))
                return Content(Serialization.JsonSerialize(new { Status = 400 }));

            return Content(Serialization.JsonSerialize(new { Status = 200, Result = PageRepository.Add(item) }));
        }
```

In controller , I wrote code above, in view I wrote code below

```
          var item = {
                Title: title,
                SeoUrl: seo,
                IsActive: isActive,
                Portals: portals,
                Content: content,
                Lang: pageLanguage,
                IsShown:isLock,
                MetaKeywords:keywords,
                MetaDescription:description
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("Add", "Page")',
                data: JSON.stringify(item),                
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.Result !== "SUCCEED") {
                        if (data.Result == "SEO_URL_EXISTS") {

                            toastr.warning('Böyle bir seo_url mevcuttur !!!');
                            return;
                        }
                        toastr.error('@Resources.Resource.Error_Unexpected');
                        return;
                    }
                    if (!isActive) {
                        toastr.success('@Resources.Resource.Success_PageSave');
                        return;
                    }
                    toastr.success('@Resources.Resource.Success_PageSaveAndPublish');
                    return;
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    toastr.error('@Resources.Resource.Error_Unexpected');
                    return;
                },
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                beforeSend: function() {
                    waitingDialog.show('@Resources.Resource.Waiting_PageUpdating');
                },
                complete: function() {
                    waitingDialog.hide();
                }
            });
```

In web config I added below,

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="999999999"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

content item  may include base64 string. How can I send this jason data to controller, even there is long base64 string.

This is error:

> Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON
>   JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set
>   on the maxJsonLength property. Parameter name: input

Comment: is this full .net or .net core? where and how are you hosting it?

Comment: have you tried changing the webconfig to allow longer request lengths?

Comment: Yes I added request length to web config. It didnt work. This is .net MVC

Comment: Would you share with us "Page" class ?

Comment: What happens if you change the config setting to `2147483644`?